# Which side is up for the undersink Contact protector?

Tags: sink

I got the Contact brand Extra Large undersink plastic protector & I can't figure out which side is supposed to be up!  One side is super smooth & the opposite side has pretty flat but slightly raised ridge design.

Which side should be faced toward the floor?

Answer (score 1):

The "woven" pattern faces up, the smooth side faces down (toward the floor). The smooth side will grip nicely against smooth clean cabinet floor surface, resisting slipping/movement.

Comment: It won't flatten & I don't have a hair dryer. Any way to flatten it?

Comment: Lay it out in the sun to warm up?